# What's the `composer require` equivalent for npm?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, composer-php

I am pretty familiar with composer and now looking into `npm`, the command below doesn't seen to change the `package.json` file like `composer require slim/slim 2.4.3`

```
npm install express
```

Is changing the json manually necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add the --save option :

```
npm install express --save
```